# How is ESR specified on ceramic capacitors?

Tags: capacitor, voltage-regulator, ceramic, esr

I'm looking for a capacitor to use as the output capacitor with the [LDO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-dropout_regulator) regulator [SP6205EM5-L-3-3](http://uk.farnell.com/exar/sp6205em5-l-3-3/ic-v-reg-ldo-0-5a-3-3v-smd-6205/dp/9388338). It says it requires a 2.2 µF capacitor, with an [ESR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalent_series_resistance) less than 0.5 ohm.

I've found the [TCJA106M010R0300](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=478-3127-1-ND) type of tantalum capactior would suffice.

However, these are quite expensive, almost half the cost of the regulator... I wondered if ceramics of type [C3216Y5V1H225Z/0.85](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/C3216Y5V1H225Z%2F0.85/445-4585-1-ND/2050191) (in the specification it says ceramics are allowed) would have the low ESR required (they say 'Low ESR', but it does not have a value specified).

What does low ESR mean at the frequencies involved with this regulator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The part's datasheet says "Unconditionally Stable with 2.2μF Ceramic", so I think you're good.

(Ceramics have lower ESR than tantalum or aluminum electrolytics.)

Notice the note about increasing the capacitance if you decouple the BYP pin.

Comment: Hi Mark,  So the ceramics I've now linked too (needed more rep) will have lower ESR than the 300mOhm tantalums ones?
Thats great - I just didnt understand what 'Low ESR' means... yep I've included the 10nF bypass cap - how high should I go with the ceramic in this case?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The ESR of a ceramic capacitor is so low it is fairly common to disregard it altogether for practical purposes in DC regulators. The main reason I find to use tantalum instead of ceramics as output caps is if you have problems with piezoelectric ringing in the ceramic caps.

Comment: Hmm...  how often is the ringing you mention a real problem?  Will it add noise or cause the whole thing to go unstable? (LDO)  If a datasheet has a example circuit with tantalum, should I take that as a requirement? Many times I think they're just arbitrarily showing you what someone's done before with the chip.

Comment: Ringing is fairly common for ceramic output caps. It can help to change to a higher spec part (higher voltage or better dielectric) or a different package size. Tantalum is an easy fix as they are not prone to microphonics.

Comment: The ringing produces a small voltage noise, but it won't cause instability in a DC converter. I would not take tantalum output caps as a strict requirement.

Comment: On the topic of replacing (or not) tantalum with ceramics, the ESR of ceramics can in fact be so low as to require a series resistor in some applications, as explained for instance in [TI's app note SLVA214A "Ceramic Capacitors Replace Tantalum Capacitors in LDOs"](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva214a/slva214a.pdf) and also at http://www.element14.com/community/community/news/blog/2012/04/30/why-do-they-even-make-tantalum-capacitors.

Answer (score 1):

The linked page does specify ESR, 300 milliOhm

Comment: For the ceramic?  Where?  All I see is < 0.05 DF.

Comment: [link]http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=445-4585-1-ND
These are the ceramics, it wouldnt let me link with low rep.

Comment: @James: The only mention of "300" on that page is in the price. Seriously, where? :)